# Stop inserting hotkey combinations after meta/leader key

Tags: vim, macvim

On MacVim I have a rather annoying occurrence that I don't have any solutions for yet.

While in insert mode, if I type  `,` (my leader key), then hit CMD-S in an attempt to save, it ends up inserting `<t_<fa>X>` after the comma.

I don't know why or what that text is, but is there any way to stop it from being inserted?

Comment: Also I'd like to add that I do not want to change my leader key from comma. I am used to it there and have many binds.

Comment: You can enter the command `:map <leader><d-s>` to see what that key combination is bound too.

Comment: In insert mode, if you type `,` it should insert a comma. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidBrown The problem is no that CMD-S in particular is bound to something. Hitting CMD and *any* key will insert some odd symbols like that after I hit comma. It's the same with something like :map <D-d> -- it doesn't have any mappings but when I hit that combination vim inserts a literal '<D-d>' text into my file.

Comment: @mihai Yes, `,` inserts a comma. The problem is the weird `<t_<fa>X>` text getting inserted after the comma.

Comment: a stupid question, what is CMD key on a mac keyboard? do we have that key on normal keyboard?

Comment: @Kent mac does all of it modifier keys with command instead of control. So `CMD-S` is save whereas on windows or linux its `<C-S>`. As for is it on a normal keyboard its the same button as the windows key (its mapped to Modifier key 4 I think on linux)

Comment: @JonathanDumaine can you post your vimrc?

Comment: @JonathanDumaine just fyi: https://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/detail?id=388

Comment: @Kent and apparently you found the problem faster than I did

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found your gvimrc [here on github](https://github.com/JonDum/Vim-Resources/blob/master/gvimrc)

In the first section you have a bunch of mapping. The last couple of lines are shown below.

```
if has("gui_macvim")
  ...

  " Adjust viewports to the same size
  map <Leader>= <C-w>=
  imap <Leader>= <Esc> <C-w>=
endif
```

The problem is this mapping

```
imap <Leader>= <Esc> <C-w>=
```

Macvim takes your `<leader>` key and waits to see if the next one if `=`. It doesn't preform the mapping and since the mapping was incorrect it insert the characters into the buffer. It seems MacVim prints `<d-s>` as `<t_<fa>X>`. So `<t_<fa>X>` gets put into the buffer what `<CMD-S>` is pressed.

To stop this you should not have any mappings in insert mode that use your leader key because there will be a short time after it where MacVim is waiting for another character to determine if your are typing a mapping or trying to insert something.

Edit: Kent also found a link to a MacVim issue tracker [issue 388](https://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/detail?id=388) that describes this issue.

Comment: I would say that the solution is to use Vim normally: stay away from insert mode as much as possible and `:w` from normal mode. Insisting on using Vim as if it was just another Sublime or TextMate will lead the OP nowhere.

Comment: Internet detectives to the rescue! Many years ago I started with some boilerplate vimrc settings. Lo and behold, they have been the source of my frustrations. Thanks for being resourceful, removing those mappings stopped that sequence from showing up.